# Dieppe to Newhaven ferry - necessary to prebook ticket?

Tags: uk, france, ferries

I will be travelling on my bike through France and eventually taking ferry from Dieppe (FR) to Newhaven (UK).

It will be just me and my bicycle and I would like to go by ferry at around 6am. I should be taking it around 16th of April this year.

Question is,

- does anyone know how busy are these boats?
- Do I have to pre-book the ticket through their website, or there is always gonna be spot.
- Is it more expensive when buying on spot?
- If I can buy it there, how long before departure do I have to do that?

Comment: Any feedback on your experience? I wonder if I should book my ticket for this saturday…

Comment: I was ok buying ticket on spot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.seat61.com/London-Paris-ferry.htm#London-Paris_via_Newhaven-Dieppe

> London to Paris for £73 one-way, even for immediate departure, no reservation necessary...
>   Newhaven to Dieppe costs £20 each way as a foot passenger (£25 on Friday nights).

However

> Buy your ferry ticket online at www.ldlines.co.uk or at the port.  There are almost always places available.

That almost makes me pause.

Here's the [FAQ](http://ldlines.co.uk/good-to-know/faq#check):

> You should check-in at least 45 min before departure.

The FAQ doesn't mention bikes but this [article](http://www.freewheelingfrance.com/planning-a-trip/ferries-to-france.html) claims

> Bikes are welcome on all services

Comment: (+1) I guess it's “almost” because it's not like a regional train: If a ferry is already truly full, they won't sell additional tickets.

Comment: Why does it (almost) make you pause?

Comment: Because otherwise I'd have said, go ahead, buy your ticket at the port.

Comment: @chx Yes that is exactly why I am asking over here. I found the same information, that basically tells you: no problem to buy ticket in port, but you might not be able to... I think Im just gonna risk it though. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The chance of the ferry being too full for walk on passengers is fairly low.  They can get sold out for vehicles, but bicycles are not effected by that since they are stored along the sides, not in vehicle spaces.

If you are buying your ticket that morning I would arrive at least an hour ahead in case there are lots of folks checking in or go the day before when you roll into Dieppe and book your ticket.

Be sure to have a couple of ropes or straps to lash your bike to the rails or ribs where you park it, as seas can be rough and knock your bike over (don't want to come down and find your bike has fallen onto someone's fancy car and scratched it).

Comment: When I had a bike on sea going ferries, the staff showed me a spot to park it with rope ready to use there. That might not be available on all ferries but ask, there is likely some usable rope and the sailors are most likely happy to apply it for you if you do not know how.

Answer (score 5):

I have been on this ferry with a bicycle and it seems safe to buy the ticket at the counter. It seems to me that there is plenty of room to store the bikes (mine was in a corner next to the cars and trucks), and it seems unlikely that they run out of space for people on the boat.

Note: if you are under 26, doing so will even get you a discount that is not available online. So there might be other pricing categories that are not available online.